# Logarithmic problem (solved)

Tags: calculus

Can someone tell me where i messed up ?

$3^{2x}-3^{x+1}=4$

$\log _3\left(\frac{3^{2x}}{3^x\cdot 3}\right)=\log _3\left(4\right)$

$\log _3\left(3^{x-1}\right)=\log _3\left(4\right)$

$x=\log _3\left(4\right)+1$

Comment: You messed up going from line 1 to line 2.  Subtraction in line 1 became division in line 2.  It might help you to put the explanation for steps next to each (or between each) step.

Answer (score 3):

You take logarithm at the second line, but

$$\log(3^{2x}-3^{x+1})\neq\log _3\left(\frac{3^{2x}}{3^{x+1}}\right)=\log(3^{2x})-\log(3^{x+1})$$

Comment: yeah thats why i did $\log _3\left(3^{2x}\right)-\log _3\left(3^{x+1}\right)=\log _3\left(4\right)$

Comment: When you take the $\log$ of both sides, you don't get that

Comment: ahh ok, thanks for that Shuri2060

Comment: @DavidSousa Consider what if $9-3=6\implies\log_{3}9-\log_{3}3=\log_{3}6$?

Answer (score 2):

write your equation in the form
$$(3^x)^2-3\cdot 3^x-4=0$$ and set $$t=3^x$$ and solve a quadratic equation
solving this equation we get
$$t_1=-1$$
$$t_2=4$$ and you must solve $$3^x=4$$

Comment: yeah i did that way and the way that i showed, but they give me different answers, why ?